# How to enable Google Play on the Gionee M3S Android phone?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services

I recently purchased a Gionee M3S Android phone. It came with Google play on the home screen, but when clicked, that just pops up a white box briefly. How do I enable Google play on this phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I had to do to get it working (after several failed attempts):

1. On the M3s, I searched for "google play services apk mirror", and went to this URL: http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/
2. Selected the most recent version (in my case 8.7.03)
3. Chose the 8.7.03 (2645110-246) (arm64+arm / Android 5.0+ / 320dpi) version. The important thing here is the -246 at the end, which targets the M3s hardware.
4. Downloaded and installed the APK. Allowed untrusted app to run.
5. Followed application prompts to setup the app, then ran Google Play.

Now Google Play works and can download apps, etc.